# Does a random sequence of vectors span a Hilbert space?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space. Let $v$ be a random variable taking values in $\mathcal{H}$ such that $P(v \perp h) < 1$ for all $h \in \mathcal{H}.$ Suppose we sample an infinite sequence $v_1, v_2, \ldots.$ Is it the case that, almost surely, the closed span of $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ is all of $\mathcal{H}?$

Comment: and if they are iid the probability of being in a closed hyperplane $(h)^\perp$ is $P(v_k\perp h, k=1,2,\dots)=0$

Comment: @Pietro Majer: this is the probability that the vectors all lie in a *given* closed hyperplane.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this, I'm pretty sure you don't understand the question. This is subtle and interesting.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but is it even clear that the event you are interested in is measurable?

Comment: In principle, the strategy is as follows: find a set $e_i$ whose closed span is $\mathcal{H}$ such that the probability of lying in any neighborhood of $e_i$ is positive. Then find $V_i$ neighborhoods of $e_i$ such that any sequence $f_i\in V_i$ is a basis. (Attempting to mimic the Paley-Wiener criterion in the non-orthogonal case.) Then, essentially apply the fact that a random function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is surjective. (As we could restrict to the infinite subsequence where the samples take values in the $V_i.$)

Comment: @AnthonyQuas of course

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Yes it's measurable: Let $(y_n)$ be a dense sequence in $\mathcal H$. Then the event is: for all $m>0$, for all $n>0$, there exist $k>0$ and rational $t_1,\ldots,t_k$ such that $\|t_1v_1+\ldots+t_kv_k-y_n\|<1/m$.

Comment: @J.E.Pascoe: I see, thanks for your response.

Comment: There's at least one gap that I don't know how to resolve. See Iosef Pinelis comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This may turn out to be a simplified version of J. E. Pascoe's answer).

The *support* of (the distribution of) $v$, that we denote by $\operatorname{supp} v$, is the set of vectors $h \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $P(v \in B(h, \varepsilon)) > 0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. We list some properties of this set.

1. The set $\operatorname{supp} v$ is the complement of the union of all open sets $B$ such that $P(v \in B) = 0$. Thus, the support is a closed set.
2. Since $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable metric space, it has a countable topological base $\mathcal{B}$, and $\operatorname{supp} v$ is the complement of the union of all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $P(v \in B) = 0$. By countable additivity, it follows that $P(v \in \operatorname{supp} v) = 1$ (the support is a set of full measure).
3. With probability one, the closure of the random set $V = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots\}$ contains $\operatorname{supp} v$. Indeed, let $\{h_1, h_2, \ldots\}$ be a countable, dense subset of $\operatorname{supp} v$. For every $i, n = 1, 2, \ldots$ we have $P(v \in B(h_i, \tfrac{1}{n})) > 0$, and thus, by Borel–Cantelli, $P(V \cap B(h_i, \tfrac{1}{n}) = \varnothing) = 0$. It follows that $h_i \in \overline{V}$ for every $i = 1, 2, \ldots$, and consequently $\operatorname{supp} v \subseteq \overline{V}$.
4. For every $h \in \mathcal{H}$, we have $P(h \perp v) < 1$, and therefore $h$ is not orthogonal to $\operatorname{supp} v$. It follows that the closed span of $\operatorname{supp} v$ is $\mathcal{H}$.

It remains to note that the closed span of $V$ is the same as the closed span of the closure of $V$, which with probability one contains the closed span of $\operatorname{supp} v$, which we have shown to be equal to $\mathcal{H}$.

(Item 1 is valid for any topological space; items 2 and 3 work in an arbitrary separable metric space.)

Comment: It would perhaps be even clearer to say that for each *fixed* vector $h\in\textrm{supp}\; v$, we have $P(h\in \overline{V})=1$. (This shows that the assumption that $H$ is separable is used, and how you avoid the pitfall from Pietro's comment above.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I edited my answer to emphasize where separability is essential. Let me know if anything is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me. I didn't mean to suggest that such an extensive edit was needed, of course, just wanted to draw attention to where your answer differs from Pietro's comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Another Try**

We say a $\mathcal{H}$-valued random variable $h$ is a **random vector** if $P(h \perp g)<1$ for all $g\in \mathcal{H}.$

If $h_1, h_2, \ldots$ is a sequence independent identically distributed of random vectors,
            then, almost surely, the closed span of the $h_i$ is equal to $\mathcal{H}.$

First we will need a lemma.

**Lemma 1**
Let $h$ be a random vector.
There is a countable subset $A$ of $\mathcal{H}$ such that the closed span of the elements of $A$ is equal to $\mathcal{H}$
and for every point $a\in A,$ $P(h\in U)>0$ for any neighborhood $U$ of $a.$

**Proof**
            For any subset $A$ such that for every point $a\in A,$ $P(h\in U)>0$ for any neighborhood $U$ of $a,$ and
the closed span of the elements of $A$ is not equal to $\mathcal{H},$ 
we will show that we can grow $A$ by a single element which is not in closed span of the elements of $A.$
We can only do this a countable number of times because the Hilbert space dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ is countable.
(Otherwise, via Gram-Schmidt, we could construct an uncountable orthonormal set by transfinite induction.)

Choose $g$ such that $g \perp a$ for all $a\in A.$ Now, $P(h \perp g)<1.$ So there must be a point $b$ such that
$P(h\in U) >0$ for every neighborhood of $b$ and $b$ is not perpendicular to $g,$ therefore, $b$ is not in the span of the elements of $A.$ **QED**

Suppose $h_1, h_2, \ldots$ is a sequence independent identically distributed of random vectors.
Let $A$ be as in Lemma 1. Index $A$ a a sequence $a_n.$
Let $B_{m,n}$ be a ball of radius $1/m$ centered at $a_n$
Almost surely, the sequence $h_i$ must visit $B_{m,n}$ infinitely often,
as $P(h_i\in B_{m,n})>0$. Therefore $A$ is a subset of the closure of the values of the sequence. (We have essentially the fact that a random function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$ is surjective with infinite multiplicity.)

Comment: The point is that you "keep going" by transfinite induction. The process must stop at some countable ordinal before $\omega_1$ as the space is countable dimensional.

Comment: That is for each $\alpha < \omega_1$ there would be $A_\alpha$ such that if $\alpha < \beta,$ $A_\alpha^\perp \cap A_\beta \neq \{0\}.$

Comment: "Let $A$ be as in Lemma 1" ... "we may take $A$ to consist of only isolated points, as in a Polish space a countable closed set is equal to the closure of its isolated points." But Lemma 1 does not guarantee that $A$ is closed.

Comment: That does seem to be a gap @IosifPinelis . Ideas for closing it?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further on why the set $A$ in Lemma 1 is countable? Of course, there exist linearly independent sets in $H$ that are uncountable -- just choose your favourite Hamel basis of $H$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, the construction, in fact, gives something not in the closed span of the elements of $A.$

Comment: @J.E.Pascoe: Agreed, thank you.

Comment: @J.E.Pascoe : Also, the following is unclear: "Choose neighborhoods $V_{a_n}$ so that for any sequence $f(a_n) \in V_n$ we have that the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization of the $f(a_n)$, call it $g_n$ satisfies $\|g_n-f(a_n)\| \leq 1/n.$" -- I guess here $V_n=V_{a_n}$. Now, $f(a_n)$ is close to $a_n$, and the $a_n$'s may be far from being orthonormal. How can you then guarantee that the $g_n$, obtained by the orthonormalization of the $f(a_n)$'s, are close to the $f(a_n)$'s -- and hence to the $a_n$'s?

Comment: @ChristianRemling: The point should be that such a chain cannot be uncountably long. If you could construct a new $b$ for every ordinal below $\omega_1$ there would be an uncountable Hilbert space basis. That is, there must be some $A_\alpha$ where you couldn't add any more. That would be your $A.$

Comment: @J.E.Pascoe : Also, what you would eventually need is, not that the sequence $(v_n)$ a.s. visit the set $\cup_{a\in A} V_a$ infinitely often, but that it a.s. visit each of the sets $V_a$ infinitely often. But this would be easy to fix, if and when the other matters are fixed.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Yes. As to Lemma 2, I don't see how to control that. Maybe that is the root of the problem.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I deleted Lemma 2 and tried using your "visiting each $a$ infinitely often" strategy directly.